# VS extension for comparing sections of files

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs

I use Visual Studio with TFS. However, the TFS comparison utility does not allow me to compare sections of the same file with the previous one (I might be wrong).

Is there a VS extension, which allows me to compare a section of a file, with the same section in the previous version of the same file? It is helpful if there have been a lot of changes but I just wish to see only a particular section of the code.

Thank you.

Comment: As far as I know, no diff tool whatsoever allows you to only compare/consider portions of the files.

Comment: By comparing same section of code in two versions of the same code file, do you intend to compare functions or some particular lines of code (say line 10-50 of ver1 & ver2) or regions (defined by you - #region directive)

Comment: Functions are not an issue, I can find those out, however, particular lines of code, say for very large files, maybe between lines 500-600. Because of changes, this can be very cumbersome to search for. Even functions maybe. Essentially something like I select a section of code, and then try and compare with a previous version, it should tell em what has changed only in that section.

Comment: Does the Annotate function suit your needs? It shows for each line the latest change that caused it to change?

Comment: It's almost the same as "ViewHistory" for a file, isn't it? Just opens up on the side, and you can see who has made a change and what the change is..but again, I think it's for the whole file, not just a section of it.